# Exception class initialization in catch block

Tags: c#, exception

Anybody have idea about how Exception class initialized in catch block.

Example :

```
try 
{ 
    any code .....
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
     throw ex.tostring();
}
```

In above example we don't have to explicitly initialize class Exception with new keyword.
i.e. Exception ex = new Exception()

Any help will be appreciated..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well no, because the exception has been *thrown* by other code. At that point, you *do* use `new`.

Comment: I think I don't have to use new keyword if simply want to display exception on console window or something like that (On messagebox).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. What's throwing the exception to start with?

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can't throw anything that isn't an `Exception` or a subclass of the `Exception` class.

(technically in .NET/IL code it is legal to throw anything, but C# doesn't support it)

Your code is illegal and doesn't compile.

For example: http://goo.gl/lALQdt

> **Errors**
>
> (6,18,6,31): Error CS0155: The type caught or thrown must be derived from System.Exception

---

If you instead mean "who initializes an exception"...

If it is an exception that is thrown by the code (yours or some .NET code), somewhere in the source code you'll find something like:

```
throw new Exception();
```

or

```
throw new Exception("This is an exception");
```

(or the equivalent in the language you are using, like `Throw New Exception` in VB.NET)

Technically you could:

```
Exception ex = new Exception();
throw ex;
```

so you don't "need" to do the `new Exception()` together with the `throw`. You can create the exception somewhere, put it in a variable/field/proeprty and throw it some time later (one row later, one hundred rows later, one day later...).

If you do something like:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 5 / a;
```

then a `DivideByZeroException` will be thrown by the CLR. How the CLR creates the exception is irrelevant. It is created and it is indistinguishable from a `throw new DivideByZeroException()` that you could throw, so let's say that the CLR uses the `new` to create it (but it isn't so... the `new` is a C# keyword, the CLR is the runtime...)

Comment: Concluding your answer any exception that is thrown by CLR is already initializes by CLR itself then why we have to create object of exception class in catch . Sorry but still I'm confused.

Comment: @OmiH You are a little confused... see this example: http://ideone.com/UHhw05 There are three methods (`Method1`, `Method2`, `Method3`) where exceptions are thrown. Look at it and then you can ask me questions

Comment: Got it..!! that means exception will internally initialized by CLR as soon as it occurs. Thanks for your suggestions.